# Uncaught Error: $injector:modulerr; works locally but not on server

Tags: php, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-injector

The following code works fine in my local dev environment, but when I have the solution hosted on a server I get the following error, after using the unminified js I get the following error:

```
angular.js:66 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
    ReferenceError: shallowCopy is not defined
```

Below is the relevant code, my index.php file including all of the file and the app.js file that is injecting my directives:

index.php:

```
<!-- bootstrap/jquery -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">

<script src="js/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="styles/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead-master/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
<!-- end bootstrap/jquery -->
<!-- custom css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" />
<!-- end custom css -->
<!-- favicon -->
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='media/images/favicon.ico' />
<!-- end favicon -->

<!-- custom js -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<!-- end custom js -->

<!-- angularjs -->
<script src="js/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angularjs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angularjs/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/login/login.js"></script>
<script src="js/questionnaire/questionnaire.js"></script>
<script src="js/study/study.js"></script>
<script src="js/result/result.js"></script>
<!-- end angularjs -->
<div class="row" ng-app="app" >
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
// app.js
(function () {

  "use strict";

  // Creating the Module
  angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "ngSanitize"])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        //$location.path('/questionnaire'); //logged in already, session still active

      $routeProvider.when("/", {
        controller: "loginController",
        controllerAs: "vm",
        templateUrl: "views/login.php"
      });

      $routeProvider.when("/questionnaire/", {
        controller: "questionnaireController",
        controllerAs: "vm",
        templateUrl: "views/questionnaire.php"
      });

      $routeProvider.when("/questionnaire/:survey", {
        controller: "questionnaireController",
        controllerAs: "vm",
        templateUrl: "views/questionnaire.php"
      });

      $routeProvider.when("/study/:studyid", {
        controller: "studyController",
        controllerAs: "vm",
        templateUrl: "views/study.php"
      });

      $routeProvider.when("/result/", {
        controller: "resultController",
        controllerAs: "vm",
        templateUrl: "views/result.php"
      });

      $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });

    });

})();
```

Comment: Using the un-minified version of AngularJS, Router etc. may give you a more helpful error message. Give it a try.

Comment: @Olezt I now get the following error after using the unminified js. 
                                 angular.js:66 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
ReferenceError: shallowCopy is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a problem of js minification, ref https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation

Try the following, note the ['$routeProvider...:

replace your code with this

```
(function () {

  "use strict";

angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "ngSanitize"])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        //$location.path('/questionnaire'); //logged in already, session still active

  $routeProvider.when("/", {
    controller: "loginController",
    controllerAs: "vm",
    templateUrl: "views/login.php"
  });

  $routeProvider.when("/questionnaire/", {
    controller: "questionnaireController",
    controllerAs: "vm",
    templateUrl: "views/questionnaire.php"
  });

  $routeProvider.when("/questionnaire/:survey", {
    controller: "questionnaireController",
    controllerAs: "vm",
    templateUrl: "views/questionnaire.php"
  });

  $routeProvider.when("/study/:studyid", {
    controller: "studyController",
    controllerAs: "vm",
    templateUrl: "views/study.php"
  });

  $routeProvider.when("/result/", {
    controller: "resultController",
    controllerAs: "vm",
    templateUrl: "views/result.php"
  });

  $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });

}]);

})();
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I am still getting the same errors using the code above for my app.js file.

Comment: Well i'm pretty sure it is something about minification, compressing, uglyfying or something about that. The above code the only thing I thought it could be, is that. You should look for another places in your project and do that same thing here

Comment: I had to use the minified route and the unminified angularjs. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I resolved it by moving my recently added plugin include to the bottom in my
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle in my appstart

this change worked for me it was working fine locally but crashed on the live environment.